# Absolute path to currently-running zsh?

Tags: shell, process, zsh

Sometimes the output of `ps -p $$` shows the absolute path to the currently-running `zsh`,

```
% ps -p $$
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1027 ttys005    0:00.11 /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

but not always:

```
% ps -p $$
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1507 ttys003    0:00.07 zsh -fl
```

What is a consistent way to get the path to the currently-running `zsh`?

EDIT (clarification): I'm interested in how to do this primarily in Darwin and Linux, but also in NetBSD.

Comment: What OS is it? It's unusual to get the arglist with `ps` without the `-f` option.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Darwin; and the `ps` I'm using above is `/bin/ps`.  For good measure, I ran `/bin/ps -p $$`, and got the same output as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CMD` output by `ps` is either the *process name* or the arguments passed to the command (including the first argument `argv[0]`). Though it bears some relation with the path of the executable, there's no guarantee for them to be linked.

On Linux:

```
print -r -- /proc/self/exe(:A)
```

On Darwin and Linux and possibly others:

```
lsof -ap"$$" -dtxt  -Fn | sed '2!d;s/.//;q'
```

But I don't know how reliable it is.

Another heuristic:

```
print -r -- ${${0#-}:c:A}
```

`$0`, like you see in the ps output contains the first argument that `zsh` received (`argv[0]`), or when passed a script as argument, that argument.

In the first case, typically, (by convention, there's no guarantee) that `argv[0]` would be either a *path* including a `/` (relative or absolute), or `zsh` (something without `/`) in which case the caller will have looked up `zsh` in **his** `$PATH` or his command hash table... If the path is relative, the above method will only work if the current directory has not changed since zsh was invoked. If there's no `/`, the method will only work if `zsh` is looking up the executable the same way as the caller did.

In the case of a script, it's the path of the script that will be returned instead of that of the interpreter (contrary to the first two solutions).

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, on my system, the last two gave different answers, because the one given by the second is a symlink; I had to run `sudo /bin/ls -l $( whence -p -- ${0#-} )` to get the true path (which then agreed with the results of the `lsof` approach).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get the absolute path of any program:
**which cmd**

For example: 
which zsh