# How to get absolute path of current shell in a sourced script?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Suppose one executes either

```
. some_script
```

or

```
source some_script
```

How can `some_script` determine the absolute path of the *current* shell (i.e. the one that is executing the `.` or `source` command)?  (Note that, in general, this path is not the same as the value of `$SHELL`.)

In other words, I'm looking for the "absolute path" counterpart of `$$`.  I figure that the current shell process must know the executable whence it came, but AFAICT, it's not stored in any environment variable.

The best I can come up with boils down to scraping the output generated by a suitable variant of `ps -p $$`; for example:

```
CURRENT_SHELL=${"$( PS_FORMAT=cmd PS_PERSONALITY=linux ps -p $$ -h )"% *}
```

This is probably not very portable.  (And it's ugly, to boot.)

---

I'm primarily interested in the case where the current shell is some version of `zsh`.  (I have a secondary interest in the corresponding answer for `bash`.)

Comment: Not sure, but does `readlink /proc/$$/exe` get what you want?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87061/absolute-path-to-currently-running-zsh .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: most embarrassing... it's my own question.  I knew I had asked something like it before, but I did not find it, probably because in all my searches I was using the word "source"...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```bsh
head -n 1 /proc/$$/status | cut -f2
```

I'm not sure it's portable to all Unices, but it works in Linux and Cygwin.